# jquery events sticky header

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky

Hello I'm trying to subscribe to the Jquery event sticky-start but it's not working on the documentation it says

```
To subscribe to events use jquery:

<script>
  $('#sticker').on('sticky-start', function() { console.log("Started"); });
  $('#sticker').on('sticky-end', function() { console.log("Ended"); });
</script>
```

So i attempted to replicate this functionality in a fiddle but it does not console log anything. How do I subscribe to a Jquery event?

http://jsfiddle.net/mamq8qe6/6/

Comment: Your code is correct. I have had a look at the jquery.sticky.js file of your fiddle and there was no trigger for the `sticky-start` event. Maybe that's a new feature. I have added the latest master to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/mamq8qe6/17/) and then it is working.